# How can I save a video conversation in Empathy?

Tags: empathy

I'm chatting with a friend and I'd like to save the video to see the conversation again later. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any empathy based recoding feature or plugin, but this task might be accomplished by a screen recorder/capturing. I personally use gtk-recordmydesktop.